# How to return all value out the for loop in golang

Tags: list, go

In python I can return how value what I append in the array

```
valuesinPy= []
for i range(len(value)) :
   valuesinPy.append(value[i])
return valuesinPy
```

It's able to return all value I want to append  in golang

```
valueappend =make(map[strig]string)
for i :=range value{
    valueappend['abs']=value[i]
}
return  valueappend
```

it's all same
**But the value  return same I got confused**

**Problem fix**
I use the `map [string]interface{}{}`  I less one  struct of slice

```
valueappend:=map[string]interface{}{}
for i :=range value{
   valueappend= append(valueappend, map[string]interface{}{
        "valueIwant append" value[i] :
     }
}
return valueappend
```

Comment: What do you mean “cant return”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to change the value of the map each time you go through the loop, or else every value from `value[i]` will keep writing to that same field in the map, leaving with the last value of i as your only value in the map

Answer (score 1):

One issue I can see is that the key you are using is same in all iterations of the loop

```
valueappend['abs']=value[i]
```

This will overwrite all previous values and you will only have the last one in the loop be saved. In the end you will get a map with just one value. I'm guessing that's not what you want here. Use can use a unique key for each iteration as follows, or something else along the same line

```
for i := range value {
    valueappend[i]=value[i]
}
```

@范紀予 please add more info and clarify what you are trying to achieve here.